# Singleton - task inside constructor fails to start/ does not start asynchronically

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton, task, autoresetevent

I have a bit of weird problem that is hard to explain. I have singleton class where in the constructor I have to run a task to initialize some components/resources.

I used 2 implementation of singleton from *C# in Depth* and in one case everything is working fine, in another case - not.

Code is available below with some comments. 
The main problem that for some reason task is not started in one case, when I am using static field with initialier and static contructor (class **Test2**).

I made some other tests and looks like with the *implementation 2* task does not start asynchronically, but starts synchronically after waiting time.

Implementation one. everything is working as expected

```
public sealed class Test1
{
    private static Test1 instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    private Test1()
    {
        using (AutoResetEvent startEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            new Task(() => TaskThread(startEvent)).Start();

            if (!startEvent.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Result()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    private void TaskThread(AutoResetEvent startEvent)
    {
        //I am initializing some stuff here
        startEvent.Set();
    }

    public static Test1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Test1();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation 2, task is never started, or started after waiting time of an event

```
public sealed class Test2
{
    private static readonly Test2 instance = new Test2();

    static Test2()
    {
    }
    private Test2()
    {
        using (AutoResetEvent startEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            new Task(() => TaskThread(startEvent)).Start();

            //here it fails to wait successfully and throws an
            //exception. Time limit is not reached
            if (!startEvent.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Result()
    {
        return 20;
    }

    private void TaskThread(AutoResetEvent startEvent)
    {
        //I am initializing some stuff here as well
        //but in this implementation code is never reached
        startEvent.Set();
    }

    public static Test2 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I am curious why is this happening and how to avoid this problems in future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it may be because of `System.TypeInitializer` during static fields initialization.

Comment: @m.rogalski can you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: `System.TypeInitializer` has problems with initializing some classes when in the static initialization process. The order is to initialize static types first and then static members and then call entry point. Maybe during static initialization, `TypeInitializer` doesn't have informations about specific types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of such 'strange' behavior is pretty simple - CLR executes static constructor under a lock. That prevents created thread from entering `TaskThread()` method and setting `startEvent` to signaled state.

After you face with such a problem and puzzle for several hours why this is happening, you start to understand why many sources advise not to use doubtful constructs like static constructors, global variables, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
And for others who come here - here is some additional info on this topic
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/05/03/static-constructor-deadlocks/

Comment: Static constructor isn't doubtful. Doubtful is starting a thread/task in static constructor.